Why did God choose Moses and not Aaron?
Since Aaron seemed to speak well and was going to be the mouth for Moses, why did God not use Aaron for the assignment? Is it because Aaron would later show a lack a faith when Moses was on the mountain?

Moses was educated as an Egyptian royal.  He had access to Pharoah.

Also God is rather prone to choose people who hate putting themselves forward. That includes Ezekiel, who was too "overwhelmed" to go out and do the job (ch3 v15) and possibly Paul 2 Corinthians ch12 vv7-9 may throw light on the reason.

We are not told so we do not know.  Ask the LORD when you meet Him.  However, Num 12:34 may be part of the answer.  God is sovereign and man is responsible.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! Kimberly Cruz please don't be discouraged. I would highly recommend looking at the Help Center's section "How do I ask a good question?". Please [edit] your question to be in line with the site's standards so that it won't be closed.

It is God's preference for choosing the weaker ones to represent Him. There are some basic principles as we discovered from Bible

Glorifying God - The weak will demonstrate His power and sovereignty, as their success doesn't depend on individual strength but on divine intervention.
Humility and Dependence: The weak will generally recognize their limits, and rely more on God. Paul illustrates it in 2 Cor 12:9, "But he said to me, “My grace is sufficient for you, for my power is made perfect in weakness.” Therefore I will boast all the more gladly about my weaknesses, so that Christ’s power may rest on me."
Avoid Pride - God avoids choosing the mighty or self-sufficient to prevent pride. The weak are less likely to boast their abilities. Paul illustrates it in 1 Cor 1:28-29: "28 God chose the lowly things of this world and the despised things—and the things that are not—to nullify the things that are, 29 so that no one may boast before him."
Spiritual Transformation: God's power is magnified when He transforms the weak into vessels of honor. It's a testimony to His grace. Paul illustrates it in 1 Cor 1:26-27: "26 Brothers and sisters, think of what you were when you were called. Not many of you were wise by human standards; not many were influential; not many were of noble birth. 27 But God chose the foolish things of the world to shame the wise; God chose the weak things of the world to shame the strong."

Moses, possibly preordained by God, was born during a time when Pharoh ordered the death of all male infants. His miraculous survival and subsequent education in Pharaoh's court were unprecedented. His name, meaning "I drew him out of the water" (Exodus 2:10), symbolizes a sense of "rebirth" akin to baptism.

A number of factors have been suggested:

Moses was the younger brother, and in the OT God rather consistently favored younger sons over elder ones. (Examples: Abel over Cain, Isaac over Ishmael, Jacob over Esau, Joseph over his elder brothers, etc.)

Moses went through a process that specially prepared him for his mission: nearly being killed by the Pharaoh's men, protected by the actions of his mother and sister, raised in the Egyptian palace to the age of 40 and thus fluent in Egyptian language and culture. He knew the traditions of the court and would be able to put them to good use in communicating with the Pharaoh.

By marrying into the clan of the Midianite priest Jethro, he learned both the geography and the culture of the desert, thus specially qualified himself to lead the Israelites through the wilderness.


The OP's suggestion, that God foresaw a weakness in Aaron's character is also an important consideration. However, it is notable that Aaron's act with the Golden Calf did not disqualify him. Indeed, Aaron would establish a lineage of priests which continued even beyond the time of Jesus, including many righteous leaders and prophets, among them such notables as Ezekiel and (in Christian tradition) John the Baptist. Moses' sons amounted to little. His lasting contribution was to bring the Law; Aaron's was to establish a lineage that upheld it.

Moses was chosen not because of his ability, his personality, his knowledge, etc., but God chose him, then shaped him and molded him to be His instrument.  Moses’ sufficiency came from God (2 Cor 3:5).  He was chosen before he was called by God in the burning brush, because Moses knew God would deliver Israel through his hand before that:
Act 7:25

For he supposed that his brethren would have understood that God would
deliver them by his hand, but they did not understand.

It is possible that God chose him and then trained him from birth, in the Egyptian palace, in the land of Midian and then called him at the age of 80. He was chosen, then training before he was called.
Act 7:20

At this time Moses was born, and was well pleasing to God; and he was
brought up in his father’s house for three months.

Act 7:22

And Moses was learned in all the wisdom of the Egyptians, and was
mighty in words and deeds.

His shepherding skills were developed in the backside of the desert for 40 years. God did not call Moses when he was “mighty in words and deeds”, but 40 years later.
The calling the Moses bears resemblance to the calling of Jeremiah, where God said:
Jeremiah 1:4-5

4 Then the word of the Lord came to me, saying: 5 “Before I formed you
in the womb I knew you; Before you were born I sanctified you; I
ordained you a prophet to the nations.

Note that by no mean was Moses right with God after he was called. God almost killed him for his disobedience for not circumcising his son.
Exo 4:24-26

24 And it came to pass on the way, at the encampment, that the LORD
met him and sought to kill him. 25 Then Zipporah took a sharp stone
and cut off the foreskin of her son and cast it at Moses’ feet, and
said, “Surely you are a husband of blood to me!” 26 So He let him go.
Then she said, “You are a husband of blood!”—because of the
circumcision.

His training did not end with God calling him from the burning brush, but it’s a beginning of God tutoring him personally. His relationship grew from refusing the calling at first, dared to argue with God that he was not up to the task. He grew from murdering an Egypt to the most humble man on earth:
Num 12:3

(Now the man Moses was very humble, more than all men who were on the
face of the earth.)

On what basis does God choose, since none are righteous, none seek after God. The bottom line is God can choose whoever He wants to choose, and maybe one of the things God looks at is the person’s heart, and God knows a person’s heart even before he was born because God knows the end from the beginning.
Acts 1:24

And they prayed and said, “You, Lord, who know the hearts of all, show
which one of these two you have chosen.

And this is why God chose David:
1 Samuel 16:7

But the LORD said to Samuel, “Do not look at his appearance or at his
physical stature, because I have refused him. For the LORD does not
see as man sees; for man looks at the outward appearance, but the LORD
looks at the heart.

